# Displaying the list of all tables in all database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

How can I display a list containing all the tables of all the database in a SQL Server 2008 R2 server?

Answer (score 11):

You need a query for each database against `sys.tables`.

```sql
select 'master' as DatabaseName, 
       T.name collate database_default as TableName 
from master.sys.tables as T 
union all 
select 'tempdb' as DatabaseName, 
       T.name collate database_default as TableName 
from tempdb.sys.tables as T 
union all 
select 'model' as DatabaseName, 
       T.name collate database_default as TableName 
from model.sys.tables as T 
union all 
select 'msdb' as DatabaseName, 
       T.name collate database_default as TableName 
from msdb.sys.tables as T
```

You can use `sys.databases` to build and execute the query dynamically.

```sql
declare @SQL nvarchar(max)

set @SQL = (select 'union all 
select '''+D.name+''' as DatabaseName,
       T.name collate database_default as TableName
from '+quotename(D.name)+'.sys.tables as T
'
from sys.databases as D
for xml path(''), type).value('substring((./text())[1], 13)', 'nvarchar(max)')

--print @SQL
exec (@SQL)
```

Comment: +1 but I typically add filters to leave out system databases (the list is usually not useful) and databases that are currently offline (those will error).

Comment: @AaronBertrand `D.state = 0` will take care of offline databases but how can you tell if it is a system database?

Comment: Right, there isn't really a system flag for databases, but I use `database_id` BETWEEN 5 and 32766. This won't leave out things like ASPState, SSISDB, ReportServer etc. but you could add additional filtering for that if you wanted. :-)

Comment: @AaronBertrand Just checked what SSMS does when listing the system database. `when dtb.name in (''master'',''model'',''msdb'',''tempdb'')`. So in this case adopting the same as SSMS it would be `D.name not in ('master','model','msdb','tempdb')`

Answer (score 8):

I think it's also worth noting the PowerShell/SMO way to do this.  This is one of those requirements that could be quite painless with PowerShell, and *definitely* the easiest approach if you need to gather this data across **multiple** servers:

```
$SqlServerName = "YourInstanceName"

$SqlServer = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server($SqlServerName)

foreach ($Database in (
    $SqlServer.Databases | 
        Where-Object {$_.Status -eq [Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.DatabaseStatus]::Normal })) {

    $Database.Tables | 
        Select-Object @{Name = "DatabaseName"; Expression = { $Database.Name }},
            @{Name = "SchemaName"; Expression = { $_.Schema }},
            @{Name = "TableName"; Expression = { $_.Name }}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `sp_MSforeachdb` procedure to do this

```
create table #tablist(db sysname, tab sysname);

exec sp_msforeachdb '
 use [?];
 insert into #tablist 
 select db_name(),name from sys.tables;'

select * from #tablist
drop table #tablist
```

Comment: Beware of sp_MSforeachdb : https://sqlblog.org/2020/05/12/bad-habits-to-kick-relying-on-undocumented-behavior by @AaronBertrand.

Answer (score -3):

Just enter:

```
SELECT db_name(), name FROM sys.tables;
```

Copy and paste the list.