# Find data size of table for several identical databases on a instance

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have several identical databases with the same schema/table structure within a instance. I need to find the size of one table that they all have. For example, I have 30 databases on a instance and all the databases have a "personal information" table. I need to find a way to query the size of "personal information" table that they all have, instead of going individually to each database.

Is there a way to do this?

Similar to SP_Spaceused for size "Data Column"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
DECLARE @table  SYSNAME = N'Personal Information',
        @schema SYSNAME = N'dbo';

CREATE TABLE #sz
(
  dbname     NVARCHAR(255),
  fullname   NVARCHAR(768), [rows] SYSNAME, 
  reserved   SYSNAME,       [data] SYSNAME,
  index_size SYSNAME,       unused SYSNAME
);

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'DECLARE @t NVARCHAR(512);';

SELECT @sql += N'IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM ' + QUOTENAME(name)
    + N'.sys.tables AS t INNER JOIN ' + QUOTENAME(name)
    + N'.sys.schemas AS s ON t.[schema_id] = s.[schema_id]
    WHERE t.name = @table AND s.name = @schema) 
    BEGIN
      SET @t = N''' + QUOTENAME(name) + N'.'' + QUOTENAME(@schema) 
        + N''.'' + QUOTENAME(@table); INSERT #sz(fullname, [rows],
          reserved, [data], index_size, unused) EXEC ' 
          + QUOTENAME(name) + N'.sys.sp_spaceused @t; UPDATE #sz
            SET dbname = N''' + name + N''' WHERE dbname IS NULL;
    END '
FROM sys.databases 
WHERE database_id > 4 AND [state] = 0 AND is_read_only = 0;

EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sql, N'@table SYSNAME, @schema SYSNAME', @table, @schema;

SELECT [database] = dbname, 
  [schema] = @schema, [table] = @table, 
  [rows], reserved, [data], index_size, unused
FROM #sz;

DROP TABLE #sz;
```

Comment: Cool, I hadn't used QUOTENAME before.  Very useful here.  And fun to see a different approach to the problem.

Answer (score 4):

I have a script that was easy to adapt and may work for your needs.  You'll simply need to replace `dbo.yourTableName` with the appropriate table (including schema name).

The script is commented, but the general summary is to loop over all databases where you have `SELECT` permissions, check the number of rows and size of the table (if it exists), and add a corresponding row into a #temp table. At the end, you can review all of the results by looking in this temp table.

There may be a possibility of using the [undocumented ms_foreachdb procedure](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/joew/archive/2008/08/27/60700.aspx%20%22%22) to make the code a bit less verbose, but that's not something I have tried or would rely upon in production.

Also, note that this approach may be slower on SQL 2014+ if you have a large number of tables. This is due to an [outstanding performance bug in SQL 2014](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/Feedback/Details/1159316)

```
-- Create a table to capture the outputs
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#sizeByDb') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #sizeByDb
CREATE TABLE #sizeByDb (
    dbName SYSNAME NOT NULL,
    schemaTableName NVARCHAR(512) NOT NULL,
    tableRows BIGINT NULL,
    tableMb FLOAT NULL
)
GO

-- Define variables to be used in the cursor below
DECLARE @dbName SYSNAME,
        @dbId INT,
        @schemaTableName NVARCHAR(512) = N'dbo.yourTable',
        @stmtString NVARCHAR(MAX)

-- Create a cursor that loops over each database that you have permissions for and is online
DECLARE dbCursor CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARD FOR
SELECT database_id, name
FROM master.sys.databases 
WHERE HAS_PERMS_BY_NAME(name, 'DATABASE', 'SELECT') = 1
    AND state = 0 -- 0 = ONLINE
    AND is_read_only = 0

OPEN dbCursor
FETCH NEXT FROM dbCursor INTO @dbId, @dbName
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    -- For each database, build a string that will compute the number of rows and size (in MB) of the table
    -- If the table does not exist on the database, we'll insert a row with NULLs
    SET @stmtString = N'
        INSERT INTO #sizeByDb (dbName, schemaTableName, tableRows, tableMb)
        SELECT @dbName AS dbName,
            @schemaTableName AS schemaTableName,
            SUM(CASE WHEN p.index_id IN (0, 1) THEN rows END) AS tableRows, 
            SUM((a.total_pages*8.0) / (1024.0)) AS tableMb
        FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@dbName) + '.sys.partitions p
        JOIN ' + QUOTENAME(@dbName) + '.sys.allocation_units a
            ON a.container_id = p.partition_id
        WHERE p.object_id = OBJECT_ID(''' + QUOTENAME(@dbName) + '.'' + @schemaTableName)
    '
    EXEC sp_executesql @stmt = @stmtString,
                        @params = N'@dbName SYSNAME, @dbId INT, @schemaTableName NVARCHAR(512)',
                        @dbName = @dbName, @dbId = @dbId, @schemaTableName = @schemaTableName

FETCH NEXT FROM dbCursor INTO @dbId, @dbName
END
CLOSE dbCursor
DEALLOCATE dbCursor
GO

-- View the table sizes
SELECT *
FROM #sizeByDb
WHERE tableRows IS NOT NULL
```

Here is an example of the results (with dbName and schemaTableName anonymized)

[image]

Comment: the connect link is broken - `Page Not Found`.

Comment: @Kin Interesting, thanks for letting me know!.  It works for me in both Chrome (where I was previously signed in to Connect) and Firefox (where I was not).  However, I was able to find the issue via a search within Connect and that did yield a slightly different link.  I'll update the answer to use that link now.

Answer (score 4):

Below code will help you :

```
-- Ref: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7892349/1387418
-- for XML Path technique learned from Michael Eriksson : http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/61855/8783
set nocount on
declare @SQL nvarchar(max)
declare @tableName  sysname = N'yourTableNameGoesHere'  --- CHANGE HERE !!
declare @schemaName sysname = N'dbo'------------------------- CHANGE HERE !!

set @SQL = (select N' union all  
select '''+D.name+'''                               AS DatabaseName, 
    s.Name collate database_default                 AS SchemaName,
    t.NAME collate database_default                 AS TableName,
    p.rows                                          AS RowCounts,
    SUM(a.total_pages) * 8                          AS TotalSpaceKB, 
    SUM(a.used_pages) * 8                           AS UsedSpaceKB, 
    (SUM(a.total_pages) - SUM(a.used_pages)) * 8    AS UnusedSpaceKB
FROM 
    '+quotename(D.name)+'.sys.tables t
INNER JOIN      
    '+quotename(D.name)+'.sys.indexes i ON t.OBJECT_ID = i.object_id
INNER JOIN 
    '+quotename(D.name)+'.sys.partitions p ON i.object_id = p.OBJECT_ID AND i.index_id = p.index_id
INNER JOIN 
    '+quotename(D.name)+'.sys.allocation_units a ON p.partition_id = a.container_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    '+quotename(D.name)+'.sys.schemas s ON t.schema_id = s.schema_id
WHERE 
    t.NAME NOT LIKE ''dt%'' 
    AND t.is_ms_shipped = 0
    AND i.OBJECT_ID > 255
    AND s.Name = '''+@schemaName+'''
    AND t.NAME = '''+@tableName+''' 

GROUP BY 
    t.Name, s.Name, p.Rows'
from sys.databases as D
where D.database_id > 4 AND D.[state] = 0 AND D.is_read_only = 0
for xml path(''), type).value('substring((./text())[1], 13)', 'nvarchar(max)')


--print @SQL
exec (@SQL)
```

[image]